# swift use of AnyClass object with as?

Tags: swift, casting, type-conversion

I would like to do this:

```
let myClass: AnyClass = functionReturningClass() // ex. String.self
if let myObject = functionReturningObject() as? myClass { ...
```

The `as? myClass` doesn't compile ('myClass is not a type').  What can I do?

Comment: What do you __really__ need to do?

Comment: In the code you have there, myClass is the name of a constant. The first line of code you have there says "There is a constant, named myClass, and it could be of any object type, and its value is given by what's returned from functionReturningClass()"

Comment: trying for subclasses to supply a different type

Comment: Right now myClass is not a type, it's a variable of type AnyClass. So like appzYourLife said, what do you really need to do ?

Comment: @SwiftRabbit I was trying to assign to myObject an object of class matching class returned from functionReturningClass().  I think that's pretty obvious from code.

Comment: I dont think that you can typecast at runtime in swift, I guess that's where my confusion was coming from. I suggest using the isKindaClass method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible--`as` must know the type it is casting to at compile-time. You cannot provide a variable type to `as`. If you must cast, then you are limited to features like generics and overloading that work at compile-time.

Think about it--what methods should the compiler allow you to call on the resulting `myObject`? It's impossible to say without knowing the runtime value of `myClass`. It makes good sense, therefore, that this doesn't work.

You can still return subclasses from `functionReturningObject()`. You can still cast them to different types. You just can't decide what type to cast them to dynamically at runtime.